# Terminal output editor with collapse function for prompts

Tags: text-editor

Is there a text editor which allows to parse output of a terminal session in the form of

```
[x@y:/path/]# cmd1
bla1
bla2
[x@y:/another/path/]# make
10000 K lines
[x@y:/another/path/]# cmd2
bla1
```

and collapse the output of a prompt (e.g. of `[x@y:/another/path/]# make` in the example above) and give an overview of the issued commands and allow to delete, cut, copy and paste the collapsed command outputs.

An example use case would be a terminal session where you try to figure out a compilation problem and found a solution somewhere in you session but can't really reconstruct why. In an average text editor one has to work with potentially millions of lines of output to sort the commands in a presentable log (e.g. for a bug report).